# z80 assembly if statement

Tags: assembly, z80

Given the following C code:

```c
int a=8;
if (a==8)
    ...
```

will the equivalent in z80 assembly be the code below?

```
ld a, 8
cp 8
```

Comment: You probably need a `JR  Z, NEXT-$` to jump to the next label if equal.

Comment: so Z is if equal and NZ if its not equal?

Comment: The `Z` flag (Zero) is set when a calculation results in a zero value.  In this case, it is when the comparison is equal, which can be thought of as the calculation of (`a` - 8) resulting in zero.

Comment: In principle you're right. But your compiler will have 16-bit `int` most probably. Then the shown assembly is not the same since it uses an 8-bit type. Just my $0.02, if you ever happen to look at compiler generated assembly.

Comment: I would say, it is very unlikely that the "equivalent in z80 assembly" would look like those two instructions in your question. Generally speaking - it is pointless to discuss a couple of lines of C code which do not do anything useful (taken on their own these lines are logically equivalent to a NOP). Also, it is pretty much pointless to discuss C-to-asm translation without a particular compiler in mind. I can confirm that the compiler I worked with (SDCC) would use 16 bits to represent an 'int'.

Comment: Your example code C does nothing, so technically, the equivalent assembly would be NOP or just nothing at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just throwing some registers around:

```
   ld hl,8     ; int is a 16 bit value
   push hl
   push bc
   ld bc,8
   or a        : clear carry flag
   sbc hl,bc   ; zero flag set when equal
   pop bc
   pop hl
   jr nz,endif

   ...

endif:

   ...
```

For an interesting take on using macros for structured assembly programming see https://dev.to/jhlagado/structured-programming-in-z80-assembly-554d

Comment: `or a` is just to clear the carry flag ahead of `sbc`?  Is that because Z80 doesn't have a 16-bit sub *without* carry-in?

Comment: @Peter, that’s right—Z-80 has both `sub` and `sbc` in  8-bit, but no 16-bit `sub`.